# How can I influence which Virtual Display (X Server) is shown after boot?

Tags: xorg, boot

I'm trying to build an info display (or Digital Signage Monitor) with Raspberry Pi running Raspbian (so a Debian distro). I need to start two X servers, where one is showing the content (through Iceweasel) and the other is an optional WLAN configuration GUI. The latter should only be shown after pressing the corresponding <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> combination. Otherwise Iceweasel should ALWAYS be displayed.

I have two simple scripts starting Iceweasel and the WLAN config. On boot, I log user Pi into terminals tty1 and tty2 (in `/etc/inittab`). After login (in `/home/pi/.bash_profile`) I start two X servers, depending on the terminal I am on. 
Here's the code in `.bash_profile`:

```
if [ $(tty) == /dev/tty1 ]; then
startx /home/pi/scripts/autostart -- :0
fi

if [ $(tty) == /dev/tty2 ]; then
startx /home/pi/scripts/wlanconfig -- :1
fi
```

I want to have two virtual desktops without a window manager showing only Iceweasel or WLAN config. This works so far, the only problem is that sometimes Iceweasel starts is displayed and sometimes the config GUI. The `:0` or `:1` argument obviously doesn't influence the start priority. I need Iceweasel to always be displayed.

I am an experienced Windows user, but have my problems understanding some of the Linux concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I found an answer to my problem. A bit of a workaround, but it works for me:

I added a parameter to startx to determine the virtual terminal:

```
startx /home/pi/scripts/autostart -- :0 vt8
```

and vt7 for the other script.

Then I switched the visible terminal with the command `chvt 8` as the last command in 'wlanconfig', so that I jump to the right screen, even if the wrong one was booted.